# XSLT element selection based on Choose not working

Tags: xslt

I have the following XML:

```
<Document>
  <Row>
    <KEY>NIKE|JB|APPAREL|MENS</KEY>
    <Period>Nov-21</Period>
  </Row>
  <Row>
    <KEY>FASCINATE|JB|ACCESSORIES|LADIES</KEY>
    <Matches>
      <Row>
        <KEY>FASCINATE|JB|ACCESSORIES|LADIES</KEY>
        <Period>Nov-22</Period>
      </Row>
    </Matches>
  </Row>
</Document>
```

I want to use XSLT to return the nested `/Matches/Row/Period` when the `Document/Row/Period` is undefined (as it is in the second `Row` of the XML)

So I have the following XSLT:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:ns="http://exampleincludednamespace.com/"
exclude-result-prefixes="ns">
<xsl:output method="xml" omit-xml-declaration="yes" />
<xsl:template match="/">
    <Document>
        <xsl:for-each select="/Document/Row">
            <xsl:variable name="period" select="/Period" />
            <xsl:choose>
                <xsl:when test="$period = null">
                    <xsl:copy>
                        <xsl:copy-of select="KEY | /Matches/Row/Period" />
                    </xsl:copy>
                </xsl:when>
                <xsl:otherwise>
                    <xsl:copy>
                        <xsl:copy-of select="KEY | Period" />
                    </xsl:copy>
                </xsl:otherwise>
            </xsl:choose>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </Document>
</xsl:template>
```

</xsl:stylesheet>

But it returns the following output:

```
<Document>
   <Row>
      <KEY>NIKE|JB|APPAREL|MENS</KEY>
      <Period>Nov-21</Period>
   </Row>
   <Row>
      <KEY>FASCINATE|JB|ACCESSORIES|LADIES</KEY>
   </Row>
</Document>
```

(Note how it is not returning the nested `/Matches/Row/Period` in the second `/Row`.

I expect to get the following output:

```
<Document>
   <Row>
      <KEY>NIKE|JB|APPAREL|MENS</KEY>
      <Period>Nov-21</Period>
   </Row>
   <Row>
      <KEY>FASCINATE|JB|ACCESSORIES|LADIES</KEY>
      <Period>Nov-22</Period>
   </Row>
</Document>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `<xsl:variable name="period" select="/Period" />` will never select anything unless `Period` is the root element of the XML. What is the expected result? Please add it to your question.

Comment: added expected output

Answer (score 1):

undefined or null are not checked in XSLT/XPath using `expression = null`, you would rather use (for node-sets) `<xsl:when test="expression">` e.g. `<xsl:when test="Period">` that there is at least one `Period` child element for the context node or `test="not(Period)"` to check there is no `Period` child.

In the end I would suggest to use template matching based on the identity transformation template and put any conditions into match pattern (predicates), but that is a different issue.

Answer (score 0):

Got it working with this XSLT:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:ns="http://exampleincludednamespace.com/"
exclude-result-prefixes="ns">
<xsl:output method="xml" omit-xml-declaration="yes" />
<xsl:template match="/">
    <Document>
        <xsl:for-each select="/Document/Row">
            <xsl:choose>
                <xsl:when test="not(Period)">
                    <xsl:copy>
                        <xsl:copy-of select="KEY | Matches/Row/Period" />
                    </xsl:copy>
                </xsl:when>
                <xsl:otherwise>
                    <xsl:copy>
                        <xsl:copy-of select="KEY | Period" />
                    </xsl:copy>
                </xsl:otherwise>
            </xsl:choose>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </Document>
</xsl:template>
```

</xsl:stylesheet>

Thanks to @MartinHonnen's guidance.

Answer (score 0):

I believe it could be simply:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="/Document">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:for-each select="Row">
            <xsl:copy>
                 <xsl:copy-of select="KEY | descendant::Period[1]" />
            </xsl:copy>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```